# Display list of related Content (Files) in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, content, contentdocument

I am looking for a way to display my related content to my case using Lightning, I currently can display attachments perfectly as seen below:

```
<span class="text-blue">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.record.Attachments}" var="obj">
            {!obj.Name}
            <!--<a href="{! '/' + $Label.c.AMEXCOMM_Domain + '/s/sfsites/c/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + obj.Id }" target="_blank">
                {!obj.Name}
            </a>-->
            <br></br><br></br>
        </aura:iteration>
</span>
```

Which returns a list like so:

[image]

I have tried iteration through {!v.record.ContentDocumentLinks} as well as some others but none seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a better answer if you can help explain what is not working ... This code gets all documents related to an object which is passed in the record ID.

```
public class FilesListApexController 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ContentDocument> getContentDocs(Id arecordId)
    {   
        List<ContentDocumentLink> CDLs = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :arecordId];
        if (CDLs.size() < 1) return new List<ContentDocument>(); 

        // Make a List of ContentDocument IDs
        List <Id> CDIdList = new List <Id> ();
        for (ContentDocumentLink nextCDL : CDLs) {
            CDIdList.add(nextCDL.ContentDocumentId); }        

        List<ContentDocument> entries = [SELECT Id, Title, FileType FROM ContentDocument WHERE ContentDocument.Id IN :CDIdList];
        return entries;
    }

}
```